# result.status value has a space before the word success

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry for the ambiguous question but I faced a weird bug in my code,
I want an alert to appear for the users to inform them that the updates are done successfully
and here is the code that contains `if()` block in which the alert is to be triggered:

```
export const updateTheProfile = async (data, type) => {

  try {
    const url = type === "password" ? "updateMyPassword" : "updateMyData";
    const result = await useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/${url}`,"PATCH",data);
    console.log(result.status);

    if (result.status === "success") showAlerts("success", `Your ${type}'s been updated successfully !♥`);
  } catch (error) {
    showAlerts("error", error.message);
  }
};
```

but actually, the code never entered the `if()` although the status was a success, so I printed `result.status` in the console and noticed that success has a space before it, like this " success".
does anyone know why is that ? I don't see anything that could be the reason for generated space.

I have another condition exactly like this in another part of my code and it works perfectly it enters the `if()` block

the status value comes from the data variable which is returned by `useFetch()` this method will contact with my API:

```
export const useFetch = async(url, methodType, uploadData = null) => {
  
  try {
    const request = uploadData
      ? fetch(url, {
          method: methodType,
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(uploadData),
        })
      : fetch(url);

    const response = await Promise.race([request, timeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SEC)]);
    console.log(response);
    
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    

    if (!response.ok) throw Error(data.message);

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.message === "Failed to fetch")
      error.message = `Unable to reach the server. Please check your internet connection...`;
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Comment: Where is the `status` value coming from? Is it somewhere from your code? If that's the case, somewhere in your code you have an extra space.

Comment: What is `useFetch`? What does it return? Also wouldn't it be easier to check for the HTTP Status code instead?

Comment: you could trim `result.status` and complete it, and maybe put things like this to discussion

Comment: This is just data that comes from your backend. Therefore, your backend is adding the space.

Comment: would greatly help if you tell us the current data from result

Comment: @Shibi it's something like `{ "status": " success" }` - I'm not sure how that helps

Comment: as @VLAZ, it is really on your BE side, they are giving you on that format. if you want to fix it on your side you can just use the trim() function.``` result.status.trim()```, to remove the unnecessary space

Answer (score -2):

The issue you're encountering could be related to the formatting of the `result.status` string. It appears that there is a leading space before the word "success" in the string. This leading space can cause the comparison to fail when you're checking for `"success"` in the `if` condition.

To address this issue, you should trim the `result.status` string before performing the comparison. Trimming will remove any leading or trailing spaces from the string, ensuring that the comparison is accurate. Here's how you can modify your code:

```js
export const updateTheProfile = async (data, type) => {
  try {
    const url = type === "password" ? "updateMyPassword" : "updateMyData";
    const result = await useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/${url}`, "PATCH", data);
    console.log(result.status);

    if (result.status.trim() === "success") {
      showAlerts("success", `Your ${type}'s been updated successfully !♥`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    showAlerts("error", error.message);
  }
};
```

By using the `.trim()` method on `result.status`, you eliminate any leading or trailing spaces from the string, ensuring that the comparison accurately matches `"success"` regardless of the presence of spaces.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).